# breezejs: navigation property is created but not filled with data

Tags: javascript, breeze

I'm having yet another issues with navigation properties but this time my configuration is WCF Data Service + EF.

Basically the metadata looks good, I have the referential constraints, association, etc... I've set the [ForeignKey] attribute in the model.

The navigation property is created on the client-side, but when data is retrieved (using $expand), the collection is not filled although data is definitely returned by the server :

[image]

The association here is between mandate_id on OpenPosition and id on Mandate.

I've noticed that the Mandate entity in the OpenPositions collection contains __deferred with the uri to the entity. I had not seen that with WebApi so maybe that's the problem, or maybe it's just normal behaviour.

Is there something I'm missing ?

**EDIT**

The client-side query is :

```
  var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Mandates").inlineCount().expand("OpenPositions");
  return manager.executeQuery(query.using(service)).then(function (result) {
        logger.info(result);
    }).fail(function (error) {
        logger.error(error);
    });
```

**EDIT 2**

The reason the navigation property is not filled is because in the case of WCF Dataservice, the navigation property is returned as an object, which contains an Array property called results.

Whereas in the case of WebAPI, the navigation property is returned as an Array.

Note that in both cases, the same data model (EF context) was used.

See screenshots:

WCF :

[image]

WebAPI:

[image]

But breeze expects an Array otherwise, it just ignores the navigation property and returns null:

```
   // needed if what is returned is not an array and we expect one - this happens with __deferred in OData.
        if (!Array.isArray(relatedRawEntities)) return null;
```

Comment: What does your client side EntityQuery look like?

Comment: sure, see my update. Like I said, the data is coming back from the server. The navigation property exists on the Mandate entity but it remains empty, whereas all the other properties are filled in ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, FINALLY it's working :) I am now using the latest commit of breezejs on github and this fixed my problem. In my opinion breeze via WCF never worked until now with ODATA2. The ODATA specification is clear about that:

- ODATA V1 : collections are represented as an array
- ODATA V2: collections are represented as an object containing an array.

The only way I could get it to work before using the github version of breezejs, was by specifying MAX_DATA_SERVICE_VERSION to 1.0 in datajs.

Anyway, that's all good now. I can't wait for the breeze release :)  By the way it's likely I'm going to ditch OpenAccess for NHibernate. Is the NH WebAPI controller as complete as the EF WebAPI controller ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the "WebApi" dataservice adapter or the "OData" data service adapter? In general, you should be using the "webApi" dataservice adapter unless you are explicitly exposing your data via OData. The "webApi" adapter is the default so I'd try just removing any "initializeAdapterReference" calls that mention "OData".

Comment: I use the ODATA data service adapter because on the backend I use a WCF data service. If I switch to the WebApi dataservice  adapter, I then get a 404 when I try to access metadata. I though the WebApi dataservice adapter was reserved for when people use a WebApi service on the backend right ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Sorry for the confusion. I should have read your email more carefully. What version of OData are you providing?

Comment: Can you switch back to OData 2.0 and see if it makes a difference?

Comment: I have tried with version 2.0 (I've changed MAX_DATA_SERVICE_VERSION in datajs and on the server and I made sure 2.0 was passed to the server in the headers), but same result. Data for the navigation property comes back from server, but the property is not filled with data by breeze.

Comment: I've reproduced the issue when using breeze with WCF + OpenAccess, as reported here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617075/breezejs-adding-referential-constraint-to-an-entity-type    I think there's definitely a problem with breezejs and filling navigation properties when data comes back from a classic ODATA service.

Comment: And according to this section (Representing Collections of Entries) of the ODATA spec, it sounds like collections exposed as an array was only for ODATA 1.0. Since ODATA 2.0 they are exposed as an array inside an object, which is what I'm seeing now. So breeze expects ODATA 1.0 format. Could that be possible ?    http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v2-documentation/json-format/

Comment: I don't think so because all of our tests are with OData v2, but I should be checking in a change later today to GitHub that works with either so maybe you can try that one.  I'll post back here when I get it checked in.

Comment: Most of the OData v3 support has now been checked into the Breeze GitHub main branch.  Feel free to try it out and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up, the issue is just that:

-with classic ODATA service, navigation properties are embedded in an object called 'results'.

[image]:

Whereas with WebAPI service, navigation properties are just an array.

[image]

Then at some point in breeze code there's the following test:

```
 // needed if what is returned is not an array and we expect one - this happens with __deferred in OData.
```

if (!Array.isArray(relatedRawEntities)) return null;

and in the case of classic ODATA service, it obviously returns null and navigation property is not populated.

I don't know how to make myself any clearer than that. It does not look like a problem with my metadata, but more like a bug in breeze.

Can you confirm that what I'm saying makes sense ? Can we do something about that ?

Comment: What you are seeing is the diff between OData v 2.0 and OData v 3.0.  Currently Breeze only supports OData v2.0.  We will be supporting v.3 in the next release out early next week.  For now, just expose your service with DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;

Comment: I wish it was that easy but I doubt it is the reason the nav property isn't filled :( I have already set MAX_DATA_SERVICE_VERSION to "2.0" in datajs and the MaxProtocolVersion to V2 on the server side. So maybe it's just not supported at all yet by breeze ? Can I expect this to be fixed with next week's release ? :)

Comment: Sorry, but I can't repro your issue with OData v2 on any of our models.  So I'm wondering what else is different.

Comment: I've edited my original post with the latest info. Note that the same issue was reported on SO a couple of months ago by some other guy : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363153/breeze-working-with-web-api-odata   . In my case, I'm using the Microsoft.Data.OData package version 5.0.0 but I've set MAxProtocolVersion to 2.0 in the InitializeService, so I'm not sure why I get the same issue.